# AWS EMR, python pyspark script in EMR steps

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, emr

I try to run a very simple pyspark script as a step in aws emr which looks like:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
sc = SparkContext()
df = sc.read.csv("s3://folder1/file.csv",header=True,inferSchema=True)
dd=df.select(df)
write_to = "s3://spark-workflow-test/"
dd.write.csv(write_to, sep = ";", header = True)
sc.stop()
```

It reads some file from a folder, selects a column, and writes it to another file in a bucket.
For some reason it keeps failing and i cant figure out why.

This script works fine in local spark, but in an emr step it keeps failing and giving an exitCode=13. Is there are problem in the code, a spark configuration or do i need to do something in the console/emr infterface?
I really have no clue about where to look for a solution.

Comment: What is the error message? Did you check logs of executors?
BTW, what are you trying to achieve with `dd=df.select(df)`? All columns are already read from the source and contains in 'df' so there is no need to select them again

Comment: Yuri, the .py file is just a test script. It works fine locally but submitted in emr steps it keeps failing and failing and i can't figure out why. Which logs should i check? The one on the steps tab in the emr-console or those messy log files in s3? thanks

Comment: First of all you should check step logs is there is any meaningful reason of the failure. If the error happens in executors then you should check logs on s3 under 'containers/application_xxx/container_yyy'. Also you can take a look at 'node/<node-id>/applications/hadoop-hdfs'. Actually, check all logs in s3 until you find the meaningful error. Without this it's very hard to guess what kind of problem you have.

Answer (score 1):

I think your error is the same then in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57271037/spark-step-in-aws-emr-fails-with-exitcode-13/57271982?noredirect=1#comment101056937_57271982) issue.

Your spark context definition seems off. Replace it with :

```
sc = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
```