# Spark Step in AWS EMR fails with exitCode 13

Tags: pyspark, amazon-emr

I'm experimenting with EMR a bit I try to run a very simple spark programm

```
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4]
df = spark.createDataFrame(mylist, IntegerType()).show()
df.write.parquet('/path/to/save', mode='overwrite')
```

I launch the app by adding a step in the `AWS EMR web-console` I select the app from `s3` select `deploy mode cluster` and leave the rest blank.

The app doesn't even launch probably because I get the following error code:
`Application application_1564485869414_0002 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1564485869414_0002_000002 exited with  exitCode: 13`

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You can see the detailed log from web console's step section. I guess your `df` should not contain `.show()` which is an action and the result wouldn't be a dataframe.

Comment: thx I noticed the mistake as well and removed. It was an to quick copy and past error :D . But sadly it does not solve my problem.

Comment: have you set the master as yarn? `spark-submit --master yarn --deploy cluster --class main something.jar` like this.

Comment: I just use the "default" when I submit the job via the EMR web UI  I will try that

Comment: How did you it as emr step? From console? then add those options as arguments.

Comment: No from the web console I also passed `--master yarn` there without it working I wrote another more expanded question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57289032/aws-emr-no-workers-added-to-spark-job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `spark` variable isn't defined in the code you tried. It might be causing the issue since you are not passing a spark context to the app.

Try adding:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession\
        .builder\
        .getOrCreate()
```

Before using spark.createDataFrame(...)

Comment: no then the code would simply break. I can start a pyspark console on the master and just use `spark`. Amazon AWS passes a `spark` variable

Comment: When you open the pyspark console on the EMR cluster, the spark context is already set that's true. It's not the case when you pass a step.

Comment: Are there any task nodes in your EMR cluster ? If not that might be your problem

Comment: At the moment I use 1 master and 1 core node. But as far as I understood it task nodes are optional anyway. When I start a `pyspark` console or open a `Livy notebook` they get the worker assigned but not when I use the spark-submit option

Comment: Yes sorry my bad didn't see that core Nodes also ran as Spark executor nodes. Can I see the logs you get while performing your task.

Comment: Try with like this : spark-submit --deploy-mode client --py-files s3://mybucket/EMR_test.py

Comment: It doesn't work it fails with `Error: Missing application resource.`

Comment: I solved the issue over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57289032/aws-emr-no-workers-added-to-spark-job/57306096#57306096