# aws emr no workers added to spark job

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I want to run a very simple pyspark app via spark-submit. I launch the app by adding a step in the `AWS EMR web-console` I select the app from `s3` select `deploy mode cluster` and leave the rest blank.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4]
df = spark.createDataFrame(mylist, IntegerType())
df.write.parquet('s3:/path/to/save', mode='overwrite')
```

now when I do this the spark job correctly starts up but it does not get a worker added.
This is what yarn looks like I have a worker there:

[image]

and this is how the spark job view looks like the worker node is not assigned

[image]

Before when I used my "homebrew" clusters on EC2 I always needed to add `config` to the `SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()` like this:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf
conf = SparkConf().setAppName('EMR_test').setMaster('spark://MASTERDNS:7077')
spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()
```

But when I do this I just get a `19/07/31 10:19:28 WARN StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Failed to connect to master MASTERDNS:7077`

I also tried `spark-submit --master yarn` and `SparkConf().setAppName('EMR_test').setMaster('yarn-cluster')` to no avail. In both cases I dont get any executers for my spark app.

so how do I do this properly? When I start a either a `pyspark console` or a `Livy Notebook` I get a working `spark` session with assigned worker nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I solved it. As a default the amazon EMR web UI passes this:

`spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster s3://mybucket/EMR_test.py`

which does not work by chance I removed `--deploy-mode cluster` and everything works like a charm, my jobs get executors. That's it ...

To make it extra annoying when you first use the EMR web UI you have two options from a drop down menu about the `deploy-mode` either `cluster` or `client`. You obviously want `cluster` because `client` would just run the script on the master. But `cluster` will never work.

**Addendum:**

I worked my self through it a bit more and the issue has to do with the `Dynamic Resource Allocation` option of `spark` if it is on (which it is by default on `AWS EMR`) `--deploy-mode cluster` will not work instead you have to use `--deploy-mode client` or nothing. If Dynamic Resource Allocation is switched off `--deploy-mode cluster` works.

Answer (score 0):

I found this on the documentation for `spark-submit`.

> For Python applications, simply pass a .py file in the place of  instead of a JAR, and add Python .zip, .egg or .py files to the search path with --py-files.

Add the argument --py-files.

Comment: what i'm passing ist this : `spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster s3://mybucket/EMR_test.py --py-files` and it does not make a difference if I put `--py-files` anywhere else but the end it fails

Comment: Interesting. [This](https://www.knowru.com/blog/how-hello-world-your-first-emr-application/) shows no argument for the step.